# T-SQL select value where value contains less than 3 of the declared characters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Im trying to write a select statement which returns the value if it doesnt have at least 3 of the declared characters but I cant think of how to get it working, can someone point me in the right direction?
One thing to consider, I am not allowed to create a temporary table for this exercise.

I havn't really got any SQL so far as I cant think of a way to do it without a temp table.

the declared characters are any alpha characters between a and z, so if the value in the db is '1873' then it would return the value because it doesnt have at least 3 of the declared characters, but if the value was 'abcdefg' then it would not be returned as it has at least 3 of the declared characters.

Is anyone able to point me in a starting direction for this?

Comment: As this is an exercise you should show some own effort, shouldn't you? :-) Might help to search for `CHARINDEX` which return `0` if the searched char is **not** included in a string, otherwise it returns its position...

Comment: i agree, you need to try some things out first yourself, it's the best way to learn. Everything you need to achieve this task can be found via the links on this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms181984.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
With 
    SrcTab As (
        Select *
        From (values ('Contains x y z')
                   , ('Contains x and y')
                   , ('Contains y only')) v (SrcField)),
    CharList As (   --< CTE instead of temporary table
        Select *
        From (values ('x')
                   , ('y')
                   , ('z')) v (c))
Select SrcField
From SrcTab, CharList
Group By SrcField
Having SUM(SIGN(CharIndex(C, SrcField))) < 3 --< Count hits
;
```

If `Distinct` is not desirable and we need to only check count for each row:

```
With 
    SrcTab As ( --< Sample Data CTE
        Select *
        From (values ('Contains x y z')
                   , ('Contains x and y')
                   , ('Contains y only')
                   , ('Contains y only')) v (SrcField))
Select SrcField
From SrcTab
Where (
    Select Count(*) --< Count hits
    From (Values ('x'), ('y'), ('z')) v (c)
    Where CharIndex(C, SrcField) > 0
) < 3
;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will find all sys.objects with an x or a z:

Some explanations, as this is an exercise and you want to learn something:
You can split a delimitted string by transforming it into XML. `x,z` comes out as `<x>x</x><x>z</x>`. You can use this to create a derived table.

I use a `CTE` to avoid a created or declared table...

You can use `CROSS APPLY` for row-wise actions. Here I use `CHARINDEX` to find the position(s) of the chars you are looking for.

If all of them are not found, there `SUM` is zero. I use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to check this.

Hope this is clear :-)

```
DECLARE @chars VARCHAR(100)='x,z';

WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT A.B.value('.','char') AS TheChar
    FROM
    ( 
        SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@chars,',','</x><x>')+ '</x>' AS XML) AS AsXml
    ) AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY AsXml.nodes('/x') AS A(B)
)

SELECT name
FROM sys.objects
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX(TheChar,name) AS Found FROM Splitted) AS Found
GROUP BY name,Found
HAVING SUM(Found)>0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Numbers Table](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/) and Joins..I used declared characters as only 4 for demo purposes

**Input:**

```
12345  
abcdef  
ab
```

**Declared table:used only 3 for demo..**

```
a
b
c
```

**Output:**

```
12345  
ab
```

**Demo:**

---Table  population Scripts

```
 Create table #t
    (
    val varchar(20) 
    )

    insert into #t
    select '12345'
    union all
    select 'abcdef'
    union all
    select 'ab'

    create table #declarecharacters
    (
    dc char(1)
    )

    insert into #declarecharacters
    select 'a'
    union all
    select 'b'
    union all
    select 'c'
```

Query used

```
;with cte
    as
    (
    select * from #t
    cross apply
    (
    select substring(val,n,1) as strr from numbers where n<=len(val))b(outputt)
    )
    select val from 
    cte c
    left join
    #declarecharacters dc1
    on 
    dc1.dc=c.outputt
    group by val
    having 
    sum(case when dc is null then 0 else 1 end ) <3
```

Comment: The OP states *I am not allowed to create a temporary table for this exercise* ?

Comment: I didn't created temporary table,are you asking about cte's

Comment: Maybe I do not get this correctly... Your `#1` is OK, this should exist in OP's system too, but what about `#declarecharacters`? You could easily avoid this with an additional CTE to create the `a,b,c` as derived table with `VALUES` or `UNION ALL` as you are filling your temp table...

Comment: i think second table also should exist in op system,i created them both to populate data

Comment: Well, we don't know. This is something the OP has to decide... I like such silly execises :-). And what I really love on SO is the variety of solutions one can find with such questions. Always a chance to find something new...